# How to make org-capture open buffers in new vertical split window in emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I modify org-capture's behavior and make it place the newly opened buffer, after selecting a template, in a new vertically split window on Emacs? More precisely, how to make capture's template window be placed below (split-window-below) current focused or leftmost window?

Comment: Do you mean that the capture window should be to the right  (or left) of the original window or that it should be below (or above) it? If you are using the "correct" emacs terminology then you mean the latter, but I find that terminology confusing, so just making sure.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to place a new window below the actual window with focus or below the leftmost window. I tried with split-window-below, but nothing worked. I will edit the question to let this more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated subject (which I don't understand completely - caveat emptor!). The problem is that there is a long conceptual distance between `org-capture` and the function that actually does the window splitting, a function called `split-window-sensibly`. So there are many places where you could conceivably interject a change in the behavior, but the trouble is that whatever you do that way might break a lot of other things that have nothing to do with capture.

The doc string for `split-window-sensibly` (do `C-h f split-window-sensibly RET` to read it) does mention two variables however:

> By default `display-buffer` routines call this function to split
>   the largest or least recently used window.  To change the default
>   customize the option `split-window-preferred-function`.
>
> You can enforce this function to not split WINDOW horizontally,
>   by setting (or binding) the variable `split-width-threshold` to
>   nil.  If, in addition, you set `split-height-threshold` to zero,
>   chances increase that this function does split WINDOW vertically.
>
> In order to not split WINDOW vertically, set (or bind) the
>   variable `split-height-threshold` to nil.  Additionally, you can
>   set `split-width-threshold' to zero to make a horizontal split
>   more likely to occur.

So I would recommend that you define your own org-capture function that sets these variables using a let-bind before calling the "real" `org-capture:

```
(defun my-org-capture ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-width-threshold nil)
        (split-height-threshold 0))
     (org-capture)))
```

and use *it* instead of the "real" one. E.g. you can bind it to what the Org mode manual recommends by doing

```
     (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'my-org-capture)
```

(or modify whatever key binding you use).

The advantage of this is that it *only* modifies how you call `org-capture`, so there is virtually no chance of breaking anything else. And you can easily undo the change if necessary.

Comment: Very thank you, man. It was exactly what I needed. It continues hiding all other windows except the last active one, but this is not so important. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome. About the problem: do you mean that after you complete the capture, the window configuration does *not* go back to what it was before you started the capture?

Comment: After selecting org-capture's template, it hides all other windows but the active one. However, after saving it, all windows reappear. Usually, I have many windows inside Emacs and sometimes a need more than one active while writing inside capture windows.

Comment: That's how org-capture works unfortunately: it would need major surgery to change that I think. You can always split another window by hand and select a buffer to show in it if you need to refer to it for the capture.